# Access member field with same name as local variable (or argument)

Tags: c++, this, name-hiding

Consider following code snippet:

```
struct S
{
   S( const int a ) 
   { 
      this->a = a; // option 1
      S::a = a; // option 2
   }
   int a;
};
```

Is option 1 is equivalent to option 2? Are there cases when one form is better than another? Which clause of standard describes these options?

Comment: I prefer to just avoid this name coincidence.

Comment: Agree. What about difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

option 1 is equivalent to option 2, but option 1 will not work for a static data member

EDITED:  static data members can be accessed with this pointer. But this->member will not work in static function. but option 2 will work in static function with static member

Eg:

```
struct S
{
   static void initialize(int a)
   {
      //this->a=a; compilation error
      S::a=a; 
   }
   static int a;
};
int S::a=0;
```

Comment: It works for all members, either fields and member functions.

Comment: They're not equivalent if `a` is a virtual function.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this option?

```
struct S
{
   S(int a) : a(a) { }
   int a;
};
```

Have a look at the following:

> **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members**
>
> [12] Names in the *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* of a *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor for which the *mem-initializer* is specified. [ *Example*:

```
class X {
   int a;
   int b;
   int i;
   int j;
public:
   const int& r;
   X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) { }
};
```

> initializes `X::r` to refer to `X::a`, initializes `X::b` with the value of the constructor parameter `i`, initializes `X::i` with the value of the constructor parameter `i`, and initializes `X::j` with the value of `X::i`; this takes place each time an object of class `X` is created. — *end example* ] [ *Note*: Because the *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the `this` pointer can be used in the *expression-list* of a *mem-initializer* to refer to the object being initialized. — *end note* ]

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are identical unless `a` is a virtual function.  I'd
prefer `this->a`, because it does what I usually want even if
`a` is a virtual function.  (But isn't it better to avoid the
name clash to begin with.)

Comment: Can you show example where `a` is virtual function?

Comment: @alexolut `struct X { virtual void f(); void g() { this->f(); } };`  Using `X::f()` here will result in different semantics.